# Remove Canonical tag from webpage

Tags: asp.net, canonical-link

We have worked on a big asp.net project since 2003  .This project has many subsystems  and for many of them is not possible to go trough and debug . We figured out a really big issue on one page . In that page canonical tag is generated automatically and after long time debug we could not find the exact place which generates the canonical tag and appends it to the header. Even we wanted to remove it programmatically but we were not success and we could not find it in header collection . Please suggest us a solution to remove this canonical tag or at least override it somehow from that page . Thank you .